# create Chart.js after getting data from api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-services, chart.js

I have two functions in Angular:

One to get some data from a web service and store it in the `this.apiDay` and `this.apiDayLabel` variable:

```
getDayScan() {
    this.btcPriceService.getDailyBTCScan().subscribe(data => {
      data.Data.Data.forEach(price => {
        this.apiDay.push(price.open);
        this.apiDayLabel.push(new Date(price.time * 1000).toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'}));
      });
    });
}
```

and one to create a chartjs with the data from `this.apiDay` and `this.apiDayLabel` :

```
public createDay(defaultChartConfig: any) {

    this.canvas = document.getElementById('dayChart');
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    const dataTotal = {
      // Total Shipments
      labels: this.apiDayLabel,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Price',
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: this.bgColorSelector(this.apiDay),
        borderColor: this.borderColorSelector(this.apiDay),
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        pointBackgroundColor: this.borderColorSelector(this.apiDay),
        pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: this.borderColorSelector(this.apiDay),
        pointBorderWidth: 20,
        pointHoverRadius: 4,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
        pointRadius: 0,
        data: this.apiDay,
      }]
    };

    this.myChartDay = new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: 'lineWithLine',
      data: dataTotal,
      options: defaultChartConfig
    });
  }
```

I call these two functions in the `ngOnInit()` function like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getDayScan();
    this.createDay(defaultChartConfig);
}
```

My problem is that the chart is created before I have my data from the api.

Is there a way to wait for the data to be there and then start creating the chart?

Like so (Pseudocode)

```
public createDay(defaultChartConfig: any) {

    getDayScan();

    // wait for it to finish so every necessary variable is declared
    // and only THEN go on with the other code 

    this.canvas = document.getElementById('dayChart');
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    ...

}
```

So I have to call only the `createDay` function in the `ngOnInit`

Or what is best practice in this case?

Comment: The best practice is to draw the chart in the callback when you get the data

Comment: I think not because I have a chart which uses multiple apis

Comment: Have you tried to call `this.createDay(defaultChartConfig);` inside `this.getDayScan();` when you got response from api.

Comment: yes generally this is working BUT I have one chart which uses multiple apis 
this means when I do it like this the data of the first api is set but not of the second and my chart is incomplete

Comment: because of that I want it to be in the create function
there I can say get ALL api data and set the variables I need and then create this specific chart

Comment: Ok great, Have you tried to get all API response at once and then fill up the chart data?

Comment: what do you mean with all at once?

Comment: Ok let me share you one example here, in few minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fill chart data after getting a response from API.

Create one common function for multiple calls at the same time.

```
getJoin(URL_Array: Array<string>): Observable<any> {
    const observableBatch = [];
    URL_Array.forEach((url) => {
      observableBatch.push(this._httpClient.get<any>(`${API_URL}${url}`)
        .pipe(map(res => { return res; })));
    });
    return forkJoin(observableBatch);
};


getDayScan() {
  const urls = [
     this.btcPriceService.getDailyBTCScan1(), // API 1 URL
     this.btcPriceService.getDailyBTCScan2()  // API 2 URL
  ];
    this.btcPriceService.getJoin(urls)
     .subscribe(res => {
        // You will get array inside res with the same number of the array that you passed API. So Use for loop for res.

        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) { // here will be res.length is 2 in this example
            const element = res[i];

            // Apply your logic here if you got different response in different API
            element.Data.Data.forEach(price => {
               this.apiDay.push(price.open);
               this.apiDayLabel.push(new Date(price.time * 1000)
               .toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'}));
            });
        }

        // Call chart function after loop complete
        this.createDay(defaultChartConfig);            
    });
}

createDay(defaultChartConfig: any) {
   this.canvas = document.getElementById('dayChart');
   this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

   const dataTotal = {
     // Total Shipments
     labels: this.apiDayLabel,
     datasets: [{
       label: 'Price',
       fill: true,
       backgroundColor: this.bgColorSelector(this.apiDay),
       borderColor: this.borderColorSelector(this.apiDay),
       borderWidth: 2,
       borderDash: [],
       borderDashOffset: 0.0,
       pointBackgroundColor: this.borderColorSelector(this.apiDay),
       pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
       pointHoverBackgroundColor: this.borderColorSelector(this.apiDay),
       pointBorderWidth: 20,
       pointHoverRadius: 4,
       pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
       pointRadius: 0,
       data: this.apiDay,
    }]
  };

  this.myChartDay = new Chart(this.ctx, {
     type: 'lineWithLine',
     data: dataTotal,
     options: defaultChartConfig
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `async` `await` to wait for the api response.

```
 async getDayScan() {
        await this.btcPriceService.getDailyBTCScan().subscribe(data => {
          data.Data.Data.forEach(price => {
            this.apiDay.push(price.open);
            this.apiDayLabel.push(new Date(price.time * 1000).toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'}));
          });
        });
    }
```

call the `getDayScan()` from `createDay()`,

```
public async createDay(defaultChartConfig: any) {

    await getDayScan();

    // wait for it to finish so every necessary variable is declared
    // and only THEN go on with the other code 

    this.canvas = document.getElementById('dayChart');
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    ...

}
```

You need to call only the `createDay()` from `ngOnInit()`

If you don't like to use async await, use [this](https://codepen.io/it-labs/pen/BjQVym) working example.

Sorry for any typo.

Comment: same behaviour as before

Comment: To use with `return await` with observable not make sense. You directly use the promise for that.