# Problem creating chart out of GET request with Angular

Tags: angular, spring, chart.js

I'm trying to create simple CRUD database with Spring Boot and Angular using REST requests and draw some charts out of it.
Spring boot sends this after GET request:

```
    "name" : "COVID",
    "infected": 500,
    "simulationTime": 3,
    "rvalue": 1.2,
    "dailyStatsList": [
        {
            "day": 1,
            "pv": 9500,
            "pr": 0,
            "pm": 0,
            "pi": 500
        },
        {
            "day": 2,
            "pv": 9392,
            "pr": 0,
            "pm": 0,
            "pi": 608
        },
        {
            "day": 3,
            "pv": 9260,
            "pr": 0,
            "pm": 0,
            "pi": 740
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my component.ts file:

```
export class SimulationDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  currentSimulation!: SimulationWithStats;

  chartData = [
    { data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], label: 'Value1' },
    { data: [], label: 'Value2' },
    { data: [], label: 'Value3' },
  ];

  public chartLabel: string[] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

  lineChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
  };

  lineChartColors: Color[] = [
    {
      borderColor: 'black',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.28)',
    },
  ];

  lineChartLegend = true;
  lineChartPlugins = [];
  lineChartType: ChartType = 'line';

  constructor(
    private controllerService: ControllerService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.getSimulation(id);

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {       //THIS ONE WORKS FINE
      this.chartData[1].data.push(i * 2);
    }

    for (let dailyStats of this.currentSimulation.dailyStatsList) { //THIS DOESN'T WORK
      this.chartData[2].data.push(dailyStats.pi);
    }
  }

  getSimulation(id: string): void {
    this.controllerService.get(id).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.currentSimulation = data;
        console.log(data);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It looks like currentSimulation isn't initialized at the time I want to fill my chartData[]. I admit, that currentSimulation initalizes fine, because I can print all of the data on html page. What might be the problem? Do you think that I should wait some time before chartData[] filling?

Comment: Of course it `currentSimulation` is too late, it has to wait for API call. Without knowing what you use to display chart it's difficult to help you.

Comment: I'm using Chart.js. How can I wait for an API request to be done? Is there any particular approach I should use or just wait like 1000ms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create Chart.js after getting data from api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60734845/create-chart-js-after-getting-data-from-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not awaiting for the http call to return the actual data.
Change the method `getSimulation` to look like this:

```
async getSimulation(id: string): Promise<void> {
  try {
    this.currentSimulation = await this.controllerService.get(id).toPromise();
    console.log('current simulation data retrieved successfully', this.currentSimulation);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error retrieving current simulation', error);
  }
}
```

And then also do this adjustments to `ngOnInit()`.

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  var id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  await this.getSimulation(id);
  .............................
}
```

This should do the trick.

---

By the way, I don't know what version of angular you're using, that's why I used `.toPromise()` for casting from Observable to Promise. However on the recent versions of Angular (IIRC Angular 11+), `lastValueFrom` is the one to use, since `.toPromise()` was deprecated and will be removed sooner than later.

So `getSimulation` would ideally look like this:

```
async getSimulation(id: string): Promise<void> {
  try {
    this.currentSimulation = await lastValueFrom(this.controllerService.get(id));
    console.log('current simulation data retrieved successfully', this.currentSimulation);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error retrieving current simulation', error);
  }
}
```

Comment: May be personal opinion, but don't use promises in Angular, at least not with API calls.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: @BojanKogoj We're kind of on the same page here, but IMHO there are cases where you still want to go with promises. Not everything should end up in a subscribe. How I personally prefer to work with data in Angular goes like this: if I need the data for a subsequent call inside the class, then I try to cast it to a promise so that I can await on it in an inline manner. If I need it only in the template file (html), then I leave it as an Observable and use it with the `async` pipe. When I need to do a manual subscribe in .ts, I use something like `subsink` for easily unsubscribing in one shot.